# Java Android Realm contains

Tags: java, android, realm

I want to get a result with contains with world I do this ;

```
  public static RealmResults<WyborTrasyRealm> getFiltrWyborTrasyLists(Realm realm,String column, String filtr) {
        return realm.where(WyborTrasyRealm.class).contains(column,filtr).findAll();
    }
```

But when I have a row with name : TAG and when I in constains have

```
realm.where(WyborTrasyRealm.class).contains(name,"tag").findAll();
```

I get an empty list how I can ignore case in realm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this and it works :

```
 public static RealmResults<WyborTrasyRealm> getFiltrWyborTrasyLists(Realm realm,String column, String filtr) {
        return realm.where(WyborTrasyRealm.class).contains(column,filtr,  Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
    }
```